# Wildcard SSL Certificates Across Multiple Websites on Windows Azure

Tags: azure, ssl, subdomain, wildcard

I have a question about Azure-hosted websites and wildcard certificates.

I’m able to install my wildcard certificate to a website and then add multiple SSL bindings without issue.

But when I try to add that same certificate to another website, I get an error message about the certificate thumbprint.

Is there a centralized location where I can add the SSL certificate so that I can use the wildcard cert for multiple, individual websites?

Comment: Can you please post the precise error message?  Are you trying to upload the certificate against for other sites, or just assign the already uploaded certificate to the website?

Answer (score 2):

I would like to report that this appears to just be a propagation issue on the side of Azure, and the issue has resolved itself.

Some more information in case others would run into this issue-

After I added the certificate using the new Azure interface (portal.azure.com) to a Website, the SSL certificate did not appear in the "Certificates" list, though it did successfully accept the SSL bindings that were added.  Navigating to a different Website, I attempted to add the certificate again, which failed.

After 10 minutes, I now see that the "Certificates" list is populated on all Websites on the account.  When you upload a certificate to one Website, it does become global for the account and is accessible on other parts of the Azure portal.

I am attributing this solely to a propagation delay... otherwise, all appears to work normally.

Hope this helps someone.